# SQL for top 5 and summarizing 'All others' not working ('All others' returning null/0)

Tags: sql, databricks

I'm using SQL in Databricks (not sure if it makes a difference), and I'm trying to run a report to provide the top 5 field values by record counts, and then to provide an 'All Other' line with the record counts of all other records than the top 5.

It's working well except that the 'All Other' line is returning null/0 for values.  When I run the code that is doing the 'All Other' line alone against the entire table, it works as expected.

Running the problem part of the query by itself.  It works.  So I can't figure out why it isn't working as a piece of the larger query.

```
with top5 as 
  (
    select * 
    from (
          select  link_location_journey
                , rec_count
                , 1 as unique_values
                , row_number() over( order by rec_count DESC) as location_rank
          from adobe_scratch_work.z_barb_test_3
          )
    ranks
    where location_rank <= 5
  )

  select *  from top5

  union all

  select 'All Other' as link_location_journey
       , sum(rec_count) as rec_count
       , count(*) as unique_values
       , 6 as location_rank

 from adobe_scratch_work.z_barb_test_3

 where link_location_journey not in
     (select link_location_journey from top5)
```

The problem is the code under the line with "union all".

This is what I get back now:

```
link_location_journey    rec_count    unique_values    location_rank
    null                 55,110,080         1               1
    body                 31,804,799         1               2
    content-rail         14,077,267         1               3
    nav-sub-menu          8,183,793         1               4
    nav-top-menu          6,564,720         1               5
    All Other               null            0               6
```

I expected:

```
link_location_journey    rec_count    unique_values    location_rank
    null                 55,110,080         1               1
    body                 31,804,799         1               2
    content-rail         14,077,267         1               3
    nav-sub-menu          8,183,793         1               4
    nav-top-menu          6,564,720         1               5
    All Other           224,633,332        30               6
```

Because when I run this against the entire table:

```
     select 'All Other' as link_location_journey
          , sum(rec_count) as rec_count
          , count(*) as unique_values
          , 6 as location_rank

     from adobe_scratch_work.z_barb_test_3
```

I get back:

```
link_location_journey    rec_count    unique_values    location_rank
    All Other            138,203,992        35               6
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your top 5 has NULL value for link_location_journey.
Change the where in UNION ALL to:

```
where link_location_journey not in
     (select link_location_journey from top5 where link_location_journey  IS NOT NULL)
```